# php replace link value

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, nodevalue

```
$links = $li->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link)
{
$link_text = $link->nodeValue;
$image = $dom->createElement('img');
$image->setAttribute('src', 'some target');
$image->setAttribute('alt', $link_text);

$link->nodeValue($image); // doesnt work
}
```

**How do I replace link's nodevalue with the new one?** (using domdocument)

There is actually one link inside li, but I'm not sure how to get it without foreach.

Comment: `nodeValue` is actually not defined for elements. Don't know how PHP handles this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (with $doc being your DOMDocument).

```
// saveHTML returns the node as a string of HTML.
$link->nodeValue = $doc->saveHTML($image);
```

Or, more appropriately, you could add the image as a child node:

```
// name should be self-documenting.
$link->appendChild($image);
```

Also, if you only have one, you could simply use the `item` method and avoid the foreach:

```
$link = $li->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
```

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Comment: for saveHtml- Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Comment: That is definitely a bizarre case and it goes directly against both experience and the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php), I would see if you have some sort of bizarre config issue if possible.

You might also try saveXML. It should provide the same output in this case.

Comment: Either way, the correct way to do this is by using appendChild anyway.

Comment: saveXML - Fatal error: Call to a member function saveXML() on a non-object

Comment: ok, if we appendchild, how do we remove the text node inside a link?

Comment: You may need to ammend that code to read $image->saveHTML().  OP, when you say it "doesn't work" what do you mean?  Is there an error, or is the change not reflected in the document?  Changes to the DomDocument object aren't reflected until you call saveHTML or saveXML and output the result.

Comment: @Steve There are "removeChild" and "replaceChild" methods and you can modify the textContent property. It is all found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the assignment operator, `=`?

```
$link->nodeValue = $link_text;
```

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue

nodeValue is a string.  It cannot be called as a method.  You can set the value of this string  directly, as it's a public member.

```
$link->nodeValue = $link_text;
```

The docs linked above should answer any questions you have.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Comment: I was just pointing out that it was a property, and not a method.  The documentation should be able to shed some light on how to manipulate the library to work properly.  Also, this error is coming up because you are apparently trying to assign an object ($image) to the property.  It accepts a string only.  You're probably wanting to insert an element, not alter the nodeValue.

Comment: I have to insert and replace nodeValue, there is a text, it should be replaced with the image. Have looked into docs, didnt find

Comment: And did you try $link->appendChild( $image ) ?  That's the proper way to append a node to the li.